# How to make the text in URL to be displayed in HTML page using Express Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am very much new to express framework in node.js , i am trying to write the text after "/" in URL in the html  page

to give an clear example , if URL is localhost:3000/XYZ

on the webpage of localhost:3000/XYZ a text should be shown as XYZ , if i change the text from "XYZ" to "ABC" i.e., (localhost:3000/ABC) then the webpage should display ABC

thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('/:param', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.params.param);
});
```

Comment: Exactly right. Or if you're using Express Generator, add this exact code into the `routes > index.js` file and replace `app.get` with `router.get` instead :)

Comment: Thank you Mr hiren and Mr Jonathan